# Is overloading a method with different access modifier, return type, and parameters still considered overloading?

Tags: java, oop, overloading

This could be just semantics and may be a stupid question, but I'm curious if the following would be considered overloading:

```
public String name = "name";

public void printName() {
    System.out.println(name);
}

protected String printName(String extra) {
    System.out.println(name + extra);
    return name + extra;
}
```

Everything I've read says that parameters must be changed for overloading to occur, and that changing access modifiers and return types won't result in a compilation error so long as the parameters are different, but I can't figure out whether the latter would still be considered overloading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, [JLS will help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

So it's not "changing the parameters", it is about *not override-equivalent*. To find out what that is, you go [to another chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2), that says:

> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are **override-equivalent** iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

And the same chapter explains what *subsignature* is:

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:

- m2 has the same signature as m1, or
- the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

How you interpret your above methods is an exercise left to you.